# Problem with a tex file in a template

Tags: templates

In [this latex template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-template-u-paris/qnqhskjxnsvh) there is a file called `abstract.tex` which is currently empty, the problem is that even when I write some text in this file nothing is displayed in the output PDF. What changes should be made to the file?

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-template-u-paris/qnqhskjxnsvh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: Please add a meaningful [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and a problem description here. Don't just link to external pages containing the LaTeX code. External links can become invalid or inaccessible, and the question could lose any value to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the abstract in the main file before `\input{Chapters/intro.tex}`

You can put this: `\input{Chapters/abstract.tex}`

Comment: Note in the linked template the file is called `absract.tex` not `abstract.tex`